# asp.net upload an image

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have an asp.net web forms site, I am looking to create a control that allows the user to browse for an image then save the image into the database. I know that saving images into a database is bad practice, but thats what I've been told to do!

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best approach to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from a sample:

```
var intDoccumentLength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
var newDocument = new byte[intDoccumentLength];

var stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
stream.Read(newDocument, 0, intDoccumentLength);
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
sqlConnection.Open();

var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentData (DocName, DocBytes, DocData, DocCreatedAt) VALUES (@DocName, @DocBytes, @DocData, @DocCreatedAt);"
                           + "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)";

sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocBytes", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocData", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@DocCreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime);

sqlCommand.Parameters["@DocName"].Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
sqlCommand.Parameters["@DocBytes"].Value = intDoccumentLength;
sqlCommand.Parameters["@DocData"].Value = newDocument;
sqlCommand.Parameters["@DocCreatedAt"].Value = DateTime.Now;

var newDocumentId = (Int32) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

Essentially all you need is a `FileUpload` control and some code to save it to the database.  (And you'll want to do some input checking as well, naturally.)  There's a pretty old tutorial which explains the concept well [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304133428/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx).  [This one](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/fileupload-control-save-images-database.html) is a little more recent.  But there's [no shortage of others](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp%20.net%20upload%20image%20to%20database).

Answer (score 0):

There is `fileupload` tool available in toolbox. You just have to writ the below code in the click event of button..

```
string filename = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
         if (filename != "")
            {

                ImageName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();

                ImagePath = Server.MapPath("Images");
                SaveLocation = ImagePath + "\\" + ImageName;
                SaveLocation1 = "~/Image/" + ImageName;
                sl1 = "Images/" + ImageName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
            }
```

and I hope you have an image column in your database so then just insert the string sl1 in  your insert query..

Comment: And don't forget to delete the file from the server after executing that query. Could get messy otherwise. ;-)